# Best way to add helper methods to context object in Koa2

Tags: node.js, namespaces, koa, koa2

I would like to add method such as `view` and `json` to the context object passed to my controllers. I do this in a middleware that runs before everything else:

```
async function(ctx, next){
  ctx.view = view.bind(ctx);  
  ctx.json = json.bind(ctx);
  await next()
  ctx.renderer.render();
}
```

these methods set some conventional configuration object (Renderer) that the middleware interprets and then renders out the actual response by setting the correct `ctx.body`. That allows me to switch template language easily and have an easier time combining API and Template requests.

Except it doesn't work because after `await next()` the `ctx.renderer` is the default one, not the one set by controllers. I suspect it's a namespacing issue, but I am not sure where it comes from.

What's the best practice to attach functions to the context that can reference context without it being passed to them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok it's [here in the docs](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/api/index.md#appcontext) I just missed it, the docs are inside a repo and are not hosted, which makes them hard to navigate.

TL;DR: use `app.context` to access the context prototype. Adding functions there attaches them to the context object and allows you to use `this` from within to access it.